# MYSQL: Date indicator for the past week

Tags: mysql, date

The following is a MYSQL script:

I have the following script to put a "1" in the field IF the tstamp date falls within the current week's Sunday to Saturday, but instead it goes back to all years, and inserting a 1, instead of just for the current year.

Any ideas?

```
IF(FROM_UNIXTIME(renprop_commercial_new.tstamp, "%U") = FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()),"%U"),1,0)
```

Comment: Try getting the year too `%Y-%U`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since %U only returns the week-of-year, regardless of which year the timestamp is actually in, you also need to compare years. Easiest way to do that is by using `%Y-%U` as your format string. That'll give you (say) `2012-23` instead of just `23`.

However, note that this will only be reliable if you're doing equality comparisons. If you start doing greater-/less-than comparisons, something like `2012-2` while evaluate as "greater" than `2012-13`, because the comparison will done as a string, not numerically.

Comment: It seems that `%U` result is zero prefixed, so it should be fine for comparisons too.

Comment: THanks, it makes sense! I have decided to rather use this indicator in conjunction with the test to determine whether it is the correct year, as it will be easier to understand later on.